# Changing the time zone on windows xp

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, windows-xp

Hello I am trying to change the time zone on windows xp and I am following this [guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724944%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). I am using c++ and it seems that the proper privilege flags are not set.
Here is the code:

```
TIME_ZONE_INFORMATION tzInfo, tzInfoNew, tzInfoTest;
DWORD dwRet;

HANDLE hToken;
TOKEN_PRIVILEGES tkp;

OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES|TOKEN_QUERY, &hToken);
LookupPrivilegeValue(NULL, SE_SYSTEMTIME_NAME , &tkp.Privileges[0].Luid);
tkp.PrivilegeCount = 1;
tkp.Privileges[0].Attributes = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;
AdjustTokenPrivileges(hToken, FALSE, &tkp, 0, (PTOKEN_PRIVILEGES)NULL, 0);

dwRet = GetTimeZoneInformation(&tzInfo);
std::wcout << "STANDARD NAME: " << tzInfo.StandardName << std::endl;

tzInfoNew.Bias = tzInfo.Bias + 60;
StringCchCopy(tzInfoNew.StandardName, 32, L"Nikola Time Zone");
tzInfoNew.StandardDate.wMonth = 10;
tzInfoNew.StandardDate.wDayOfWeek = 0;
tzInfoNew.StandardDate.wDay = 5;
tzInfoNew.StandardDate.wHour = 2;

StringCchCopy(tzInfoNew.DaylightName, 32, L"Nikola Daylight Zone");
tzInfoNew.DaylightDate.wMonth = 4;
tzInfoNew.DaylightDate.wDayOfWeek = 0;
tzInfoNew.DaylightDate.wDay = 1;
tzInfoNew.DaylightDate.wHour = 2;
tzInfoNew.DaylightBias = -60;


if( !SetTimeZoneInformation(&tzInfoNew ) ) 
{
    printf("STZI failed (%d)\n", GetLastError());
}
dwRet = GetTimeZoneInformation(&tzInfoTest);
std::wcout << "STANDARD NEW NAME: " << tzInfoTest.StandardName << std::endl;
std::wcout << "STANDARD NEW DAYLIGHT NAME: " << tzInfoTest.DaylightName << std::endl;

tkp.Privileges[0].Attributes = 0; 
AdjustTokenPrivileges(hToken, FALSE, &tkp, 0, (PTOKEN_PRIVILEGES) NULL, 0);
```

EDIT:
I have inserted this method in my project, and I have some weird problem. Anyways I am using the following structures:

```
typedef struct {
    unsigned short month;
    unsigned short week;
    unsigned short day;
} dstDate;

typedef struct {
    unsigned short hour;
    unsigned short minute;
    unsigned short second;
} dstTime;
```

And here is the whole method together:

```
bool::setTimeZone(short int timeZone, short int dstOffset, dstDate& sDate, dstTime& sTime, dstDate& eDate, dstTime& eTime){
  bool res = true;

  TIME_ZONE_INFORMATION tzInfoNew;

  HANDLE hToken;
  TOKEN_PRIVILEGES tkp;

  // Get the necessary priviledge to perform time zone setting operation
  OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES|TOKEN_QUERY, &hToken);
  LookupPrivilegeValue(NULL, SE_SYSTEMTIME_NAME , &tkp.Privileges[0].Luid);
  tkp.PrivilegeCount = 1;
  tkp.Privileges[0].Attributes = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;
  AdjustTokenPrivileges(hToken, FALSE, &tkp, 0, (PTOKEN_PRIVILEGES)NULL, 0);

  // Fill the TIME_ZONE_INFORMATION structure
  ZeroMemory(&tzInfoNew, sizeof(tzInfoNew));
  tzInfoNew.Bias = (LONG) -timeZone;

  // Start of DST
  // If the following six lines are executed, then setting the time zone fails
  // i.e. it goes with result status 0, but the time zone is not changed
  tzInfoNew.DaylightDate.wMonth = sDate.month;
  tzInfoNew.DaylightDate.wDayOfWeek = sDate.week;
  tzInfoNew.DaylightDate.wDay = sDate.day;
  tzInfoNew.DaylightDate.wHour = sTime.hour;
  tzInfoNew.DaylightDate.wMinute = sTime.minute;
  tzInfoNew.DaylightBias = dstOffset;

  // End of DST
  tzInfoNew.StandardDate.wMonth = eDate.month;
  tzInfoNew.StandardDate.wDayOfWeek = eDate.week;
  tzInfoNew.StandardDate.wDay = eDate.day;
  tzInfoNew.StandardDate.wHour = eTime.hour;
  tzInfoNew.StandardDate.wMinute = eTime.minute;

  if(!SetTimeZoneInformation(&tzInfoNew)) {
    printf("STZI failed (%d)\n", GetLastError());
    res = false; 
  }

  tkp.Privileges[0].Attributes = 0; 
  AdjustTokenPrivileges(hToken, FALSE, &tkp, 0, (PTOKEN_PRIVILEGES) NULL, 0);

  return (res);
}
```

So SetTimeZoneInformation returns status OK, but the TimeZone is not set. And the problem only occurs when DaylightDate information is set, otherwise it's ok.

Comment: What is the error value?  The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724944%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) states `An application must have the SE_TIME_ZONE_NAME privilege for this function to succeed.`  There's also example code.

Comment: SE_TIME_ZONE_NAME is implemented since Windows Vista, therefore you can't use it for XP. The documentation states that for XP SE_SYSTEMTIME_NAME need to be used.
There is no error cuz the function returns 0. But when I retrieve the time zone information later, it whows that the time zone hasn't been changed

Comment: You're right, I missed the XP note, sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem I didn't use the ZeroMemory macro for the TimeZoneInformation structure before setting any of the data.

```
ZeroMemory(&tzInfoNew, sizeof(tzInfoNew));
tzInfoNew.Bias = 0;
StringCchCopy(tzInfoNew.StandardName, 32, L"Test Time Zone");
.....
```

I thought that it is irrelevant to use it. But it did the trick and I am not quite sure why because I've set all the necessary information and the structure was full at the moment of setting the time zone.

Comment: Glad you figured it out.  It looks like `StandardBias` and some variables in the `SYSTEMTIME` struct would have been uninitialized without that, and based on the complicated rules for filling it out you're almost guaranteed a weird conflict.

Comment: Yes you are right, but it confused me that there was not any error code

Comment: There is a new problem now, please see the EDIT section from the question.